# Double-Tap The Nob Of A UISlider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uislider

In my appliction on double tapping the nob of slider a new view should be displayed, but I don't know which method or what code I have to implement for double tapping.

If you have any code or method for double tapping the nob then please provide it, as it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NSSlider is Mac OS X only - do you mean UISlider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO question adds a double touch to a UIButton: [Double Touch on UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109582/double-touch-on-uibutton)  The principle is the same for a UISlider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more relevant answer regarding how to set a selector for the touchDownRepeat UIControlEvent: [Detect double-tap on UISlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392550/detect-double-tap-on-uislider)